# Grouping clusters based on one feature column

Tags: python, grouping, cluster-analysis

I have not clustered data in a while and at the moment i have a massive list of accounts with their perspective areas (or OUs in the table below).

I have used kmeans and kmodes to try and cluster based on OU - meaning that I want the output to group the 17 OUs i have and cluster them based on the provided information. Thus far the output has provided me with clustering based on each record individually and not based on each OU. can some one help me figure out how to group the output then cluster somehow? below is the same of the code used.
[image]

```
# Building the model with 3 clusters
kmode = KModes(n_clusters=3, init = "random", n_init = 5, verbose=1)
clusters = kmode.fit_predict(df)
clusters
#insert the predicted cluster values in our original dataset.
df.insert(0, "Cluster", clusters, True)
df.head(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to your data set, but below is a generic example of how to do clustering.

```
# Cluster analysis, or clustering, is an unsupervised machine learning task.
# It involves automatically discovering natural grouping in data. Unlike supervised learning (like predictive modeling), 
# clustering algorithms only interpret the input data and find natural groups or clusters in feature space.

import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

mtcars = sm.datasets.get_rdataset("mtcars", "datasets", cache=True).data
df_cars = pd.DataFrame(mtcars)
df_cars.head()

from numpy import unique
from numpy import where
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from matplotlib import pyplot

# define dataset
X = df_cars[['mpg','hp']]


# define the model
model = KMeans(n_clusters=8)
# fit the model
model.fit(X)

# assign a cluster to each example
yhat = model.predict(X)

X['kmeans']=yhat

pyplot.scatter(X['mpg'], X['hp'], c=X['kmeans'], cmap='rainbow', s=50, alpha=0.8)
```

[image]

See the link below for more details.

https://github.com/ASH-WICUS/Notebooks/blob/master/Clustering%20Algorithms%20Compared.ipynb